# Why does this integral give a different answer? a water tank depletes at 10000g per day, the tank starts at 150,000 gallons

Tags: calculus, integration

How long before the tank runs dry?

So, this is basic division. take the $\frac{150,000}{10000}$ to get the days it takes for the water tank to deplete right?

To set this up using integral form, would it be

$$150000 - \int_0^t 10000t dt$$

Without the $t$ in $10,000$ the answer is identical to the division answer. However, shouldn't the $t$ be there to indicate per day?

Thank you

Comment: There should not be a $t$ in there. The rate of depletion is a constant $10000$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is legal but sometimes confusing to use the same variable (here $t$) as the limit of an integration and the dummy variable, so I will use $u$ for the integration variable.  No, doing it with the integral there should not be a $t$  (or $u$) in the integrand.  The amount of water that flows out in a short interval of time $dt$ is $10000 dt$, so the amount in the tank at time $t$ is $150000-\int_0^t 10000 du=150000-10000t$ just like you got by algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for the tank's volume with respect to $t$ is:

$v = 150000 - 10000t$

If you're trying to solve for $v = 0$, the integral doesn't come into play at all.

Comment: is 10000t equivalent to integral from 0 to t for 10000?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$15000 = -\int\limits_{0}^{t}  \,1000 dt$

$15000 = -[1000t]_0^t=-(1000.(0)-1000.t)$

You get your $t$ now.